# Create multiple data frames from one -python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a large file (>500 rows) with multiple data points for each unique item in the list, something like :

| cheese | weight | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gouda | 1.4 | AL |
| gouda | 2 | TX |
| gouda | 1.2 | CA |
| cheddar | 5.3 | AL |
| cheddar | 6 | MN |
| chaddar | 2 | WA |
| Havarti | 4 | CA |
| Havarti | 4.2 | AL |

I want to make data frames for each cheese to store the relevant data

I have this:

```
main_cheese_file = pd.read_csv('CheeseMaster.csv')

cut_the_cheese = main_cheese_file.cheese.unique()
melted = {elem: pd.DataFrame() for elem in cut_the_cheese}

for slice in melted.slice():
    melted[slice] = main_cheese_file[:][main_cheese_file.cheese == slice]
```

to split it up on the unique thing I want.

What I want to do with it is make df's that can be exported for each cheese with the cheese name as the file name.

So far I can force it with

```
 melted['Cheddar'].to_csv('Cheddar.csv')
```

and get the Cheddars ....

but I don't want to have to know and type out each type of cheese on the list of 500 rows...

Is there a way to add this to my loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over a groupby object

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CheeseMaster.csv')
for k,v in df.groupby('cheese'):
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks! This does look a lot simpler - It only split out one csv file called {k} though ...

Comment: @PorscheAdams make sure to use the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/): `f'{k}.csv'`

Comment: well - that makes a difference! thank you! and thanks for helping me edit the question - I could not figure out how to make a nice table for my cheeses!

Comment: @PorscheAdams No problem and good luck with all that cheese.